# Python 3.5.2 internet explorer control

Tags: python, image, download

how do i open a download link like http://ops.epo.org/3.1/rest-services/published-data/images/EP/1000000/A1/thumbnail?Range=1 in the Internet Explorer and save it without pushing 'save' in a file like '1.jpg'? 
I heard about the 'internet explorer control'. 
Can you help me?

I would like to have a programm that can download a lot of images like in this link automatically without pushing every time 'save'.

Comment: Is there some reason you want to use Internet Explorer specifically?  It's relatively easy to download the file without it using Python.

Comment: Agree with Patrick. Are you attempting some web automation testing?  In that case, you should be looking at the selenium package. However, if you just need the file, there are better ways to get the file without using IE.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh
 
I would like to have a program that download pictures like in this link automatically. The link would change every download

Comment: use http requests (using request  library) to download the file, no need to use IE.

Comment: @saurabhbaid     I cant find how it should work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like its a PDF file. This could be achieved using basic request example

```
import requests
url='http://ops.epo.org/3.1/rest-services/published-data/images/EP/1000000/A1/thumbnail?Range=1'
r = requests.get(url)
with open('1.pdf', 'wb') as fh:
    fh.write(r.content)
```

Comment: I cant finde a module like 'requests'

Comment: on command propmt do `pip install requests`  And if it cant find `pip` then google it on how to install it

Comment: Thank you , you helped me a lot :)